# How to Transfer large File using WIFI and without DataConnection On

Tags: file-transfer

I am using Lumia 535. and I am using Shareit for transfer the file via wifi.
that time its asking data Connection "ON".(with hotspot). 
without data connection ON, how can i transfer the Large File to Other mobiles.

Because my databalance is sharing to other mobile. how to avoid this ???

Comment: Which app is that? It doesn't appear to be [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/shareit/9nblggh094kg)?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you can't just send the file via Bluetooth?

Comment: its this very large file so for bluetooth take very long time

Comment: please advice to transfer large file any app?